# CSS: Input fields with submit buttons styling

Tags: css

I am currently working with an input field that will do search for my page. But I am undergoing some css styling issues. I have placed inside the input field the submit button which is an image of a magnifying glass. the problem is that the button does not stay in its place through cross browsers. It looks ok in firefox but others browsers it looks bad.

How can i get the submit button to stay inside the input field at all times? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/)

thank you!

**CSS related to object**

```
<style>
.search-input {
    padding: 0 5px 0 22px;
    border: 2px solid #DADADA;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;

    background: #FFF; /* old browsers */

}

.search-input li {
list-style: none outside none;
}


.search-submit {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: none;
    background: url(http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/mag-glass.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
     right: 170px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    top: 60px;
}

.search{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<div class="search"><input type="text" class="search-input" name="search" value="Search"/><input type="submit" class="search-submit" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this much better approach I came across. It works well and tested with web developer tools. Cheers@!!!

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <form id="search">
        <input id="searchField" type="text" />
        <input id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#search{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}


#searchField{
    border: 1px solid #FFEDE8;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 140px;}


#searchSubmit{
    background: url("http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/mag-glass.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 20px;
}
```